# UWP BitmapImage SetSource from MemoryStream hangs

Tags: c#, binding, uwp, bitmapimage

In my UWP app i store images in an SQLite db in form of byte[]. Then as i retrieve my objects from the db i bind them to a GridView data template which has an Image control. As i cant bind the Image's Source directly to the array, so i have created a BitmapImage property in my object's class to bind the Image control to:

```
    public BitmapImage Icon
    {
        get
        {
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream(icon))
            {
                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                var img = new BitmapImage();
                img.SetSource(stream.AsRandomAccessStream());
                return img;
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is, my app hangs on the img.SetSource line.
After some experimenting, i have found that this problem can be overcome with a second MemoryStream:

```
    public BitmapImage Icon
    {
        get
        {
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream(icon))
            {
                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                var s2 = new MemoryStream();
                stream.CopyTo(s2);
                s2.Position = 0;
                var img = new BitmapImage();
                img.SetSource(s2.AsRandomAccessStream());
                s2.Dispose();
                return img;
            }
        }
    }
```

For some reason it works, does not hang. I wonder why? And how to deal with this situation properly? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

i'll suggest you use the IValueConverter interface before showing the image in your app.

```
class ImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (value == null || !(value is byte[]))
            return null;
        using (InMemoryRandomAccessStream ms = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
        {
            using (DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(ms.GetOutputStreamAt(0)))
            {
                writer.WriteBytes((byte[])value);
                writer.StoreAsync().GetResults();
            }
            var image = new BitmapImage();
            image.SetSource(ms);
            return image;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: This perfectly worked for me and the hanging issue in my project had been fixed from this DataWriter. Thanks for your information.

Answer (score 2):

I use an extension method that I use into the converter:

```
    public static BitmapImage AsBitmapImage(this byte[] byteArray)
    {
        if (byteArray != null)
        {
            using (var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
            {
                stream.WriteAsync(byteArray.AsBuffer()).GetResults(); 
                          // I made this one synchronous on the UI thread;
                          // this is not a best practice.
                var image = new BitmapImage();
                stream.Seek(0);
                image.SetSource(stream);
                return image;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use Base64? Save Base64 Image in sqlite database column and bind it to Image control easily.

```
<Image Source="{Binding Path=imagedata}" Height="120"  Width="120"></Image>
```

it is much easier to bind image inside Gridview from sqlite db.

Comment: Base64 increases memory usage

Answer (score 0):

I've had an issues printing images loading from RandomAccessStreams until I found this.  They load fine in the app for visual but would hang the UI when generating print previews dynamically.

Conversion works perfectly, cheers.

```
private BitmapImage ConvertImage(string str) {
byte[] imgData = Convert.FromBase64String(str);
using (InMemoryRandomAccessStream ms = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
{
    using (DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(ms.GetOutputStreamAt(0)))
    {
        writer.WriteBytes(imgData);
        writer.StoreAsync.GetResults();
    }
    BitmapImage result = new BitmapImage();
    result.SetSource(ms);
    return result;
}}
```